# Command-line Tic-Tac-Toc in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust

I implemented Tic-Tac-Toe in Rust to learn the language.

I split the implementation into two files: `game.rs` contains the actual game logic, and `main.rs` contains the main function and the command-line UI.

I'm interested in any feedback. One particular question I have: I'm interested in trying to implement a GUI interface for the game – have I split the logic correctly between `main.rs` and `game.rs` so that `game.rs` could be reused in a GUI version?

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "tic-tac-toe"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Stephen Wade <stephen@stephenwade.me>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rustyline = "7.1.0"
```

**game.rs**

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub enum BoardValue {
    Filled(Player),
    Empty,
}

impl fmt::Display for BoardValue {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Filled(player) => write!(f, "{}", player),
            Self::Empty => write!(f, " "),
        }
    }
}

impl Default for BoardValue {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::Empty
    }
}

impl BoardValue {
    fn player(self) -> Player {
        if let Self::Filled(player) = self {
            player
        } else {
            panic!("not filled")
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
pub enum Player {
    X,
    O,
}

impl fmt::Display for Player {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match self {
                Self::X => "X",
                Self::O => "O",
            }
        )
    }
}

impl Default for Player {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Player::X
    }
}

type BoardType = [[BoardValue; 3]; 3];

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Board(BoardType);

impl Deref for Board {
    type Target = BoardType;

    fn deref(&self) -> &BoardType {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Board {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut BoardType {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Board {
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        writeln!(f, "┌───┬───┬───┐")?;
        writeln!(f, "│ {} │ {} │ {} │", self[0][0], self[0][1], self[0][2])?;
        writeln!(f, "├───┼───┼───┤")?;
        writeln!(f, "│ {} │ {} │ {} │", self[1][0], self[1][1], self[1][2])?;
        writeln!(f, "├───┼───┼───┤")?;
        writeln!(f, "│ {} │ {} │ {} │", self[2][0], self[2][1], self[2][2])?;
        write!  (f, "└───┴───┴───┘")
    }
}

impl Board {
    fn get_winnable_slices(&self) -> Vec<[&BoardValue; 3]> {
        vec![
            // Horizontal
            [&self[0][0], &self[0][1], &self[0][2]],
            [&self[1][0], &self[1][1], &self[1][2]],
            [&self[2][0], &self[2][1], &self[2][2]],
            // Vertical
            [&self[0][0], &self[1][0], &self[2][0]],
            [&self[0][1], &self[1][1], &self[2][1]],
            [&self[0][2], &self[1][2], &self[2][2]],
            // Diagonal
            [&self[0][0], &self[1][1], &self[2][2]],
            [&self[0][2], &self[1][1], &self[2][0]],
        ]
    }

    fn get_all_cells(&self) -> Vec<&BoardValue> {
        self.iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<&BoardValue>>()
    }
}

pub struct Game {
    pub board: Board,
    pub current_player: Player,
}

pub enum GameStatus {
    Continue,
    PlayerWins(Player),
    Draw,
}

pub enum PlayError {
    InvalidMove,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Game {
            board: Board::default(),
            current_player: Player::default(),
        }
    }

    pub fn play(&mut self, row: usize, column: usize) -> Result<GameStatus, PlayError> {
        if matches!(self.board[row][column], BoardValue::Filled(_)) {
            return Err(PlayError::InvalidMove);
        }

        self.board[row][column] = BoardValue::Filled(self.current_player);

        let game_status = self.get_game_status();

        if matches!(game_status, GameStatus::Continue) {
            self.current_player = match self.current_player {
                Player::X => Player::O,
                Player::O => Player::X,
            };
        }

        Ok(game_status)
    }

    fn get_game_status(&self) -> GameStatus {
        for slice in self.board.get_winnable_slices() {
            if matches!(*slice[0], BoardValue::Filled(_))
                && slice[0] == slice[1]
                && slice[1] == slice[2]
            {
                return GameStatus::PlayerWins(slice[0].player());
            }
        }

        if self
            .board
            .get_all_cells()
            .into_iter()
            .all(|cell| matches!(*cell, BoardValue::Filled(_)))
        {
            return GameStatus::Draw;
        }

        GameStatus::Continue
    }
}
```

**main.rs**

````rust
mod game;

use game::*;

use std::str;
use rustyline::Editor;

fn main() {
    let mut game = Game::new();

    println!("Welcome to tic tac toe!");
    loop {
        println!("{}", game.board);
        println!("It's {}'s turn.", game.current_player);

        let inputs = match get_row_and_column() {
            Ok(inputs) => inputs,
            Err(_) => return,
        };
        match game.play(inputs.0, inputs.1) {
            Ok(GameStatus::Continue) => continue,
            Ok(GameStatus::Draw) => {
                println!("{}", game.board);
                println!("It's a draw.");
                return;
            }
            Ok(GameStatus::PlayerWins(player)) => {
                println!("{}", game.board);
                println!("{} wins!", player);
                return;
            }
            Err(PlayError::InvalidMove) => {
                println!("Invalid move. Please try again.");
            }
        };
    }
}

fn get_row_and_column() -> Result<(usize, usize), ()> {
    let strings = match read_row_and_column_strings() {
        Ok(strings) => strings,
        Err(_) => return Err(()),
    };

    let numbers = match parse_row_and_column_strings(strings) {
        Ok(numbers) => numbers,
        Err(_) => return Err(()),
    };

    Ok((numbers.0 - 1, numbers.1 - 1))
}

fn parse_row_and_column_strings(
    input: (String, String),
) -> Result<(usize, usize), <usize as str::FromStr>::Err> {
    let row: usize = input.0.parse()?;
    let column: usize = input.1.parse()?;

    Ok((row, column))
}

fn read_row_and_column_strings() -> Result<(String, String), rustyline::error::ReadlineError> {
    let mut rl = Editor::<()>::new();

    let valid_inputs: Vec<&str> = vec!["1", "2", "3"];
    let mut row_line: String;
    let mut column_line: String;

    loop {
        row_line = rl.readline("Enter a row (1, 2, 3): ")?;
        if valid_inputs.iter().any(|&s| row_line == s) {
            break;
        };
    }
    loop {
        column_line = rl.readline("Enter a column (1, 2, 3): ")?;
        if valid_inputs.iter().any(|&s| column_line == s) {
            break;
        };
    }

    Ok((row_line, column_line))
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General impression

The code is clear and concise —
it is a great pleasure to read your code.
This review is thus less about problems
than it is about pointing out opportunities to simplify the code.

The split between game logic and UI also seems fine —
I wouldn't worry too much about it at this point.

## Naming

Some personal thoughts on naming:

- simplify `BoardValue` to `Cell` or similar;
- rename `X` and `O` to `Cross` and `Nought` for more legibility;
- rename `BoardValue::player` to something along the lines of
  `BoardValue::unwrap_player` (following `Option::unwrap`),
  to clearly indicate its panicking behavior;
- rename `play`, which is too generic, to `try_place`.

## User interface

I would index the board by

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
+---+---+---+
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+
```

rather than use `(row, column)`, for simplicity.

## Board computation

`get_winnable_slices` and `get_all_cells` feel wasteful —
an iterator or callback interface should be possible in theory.

## Using crates

There are some crates you can use to reduce boilerplate:

- (highly recommended) [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow) for error handling;
- [`derive_more`](https://docs.rs/derive_more) for deriving `Display`, `Deref`, and `DerefMut`;
- [`smart_default`](https://docs.rs/smart-default) for deriving `Default`;
- a [table rendering crate](https://lib.rs/search?q=table).

## Helper functions

Ideas for helper functions:

- `BoardValue::is_filled`, to reduce the number of `matches!`;
- `Player::toggle`, to toggle the player.

## Miscellaneous

For `BoardValue` and `Player`,
I would derive `Eq` in addition to `PartialEq`.

Is there a specific reason why `X` is the default player?
I would leave `Default` out if the selection is arbitrary.

For `Game::new`, you can `derive(Default)` and then call it.

Answer (score 2):

Nicely organized code! In addition to what L.F. suggested:

- The `fn player(self)` looks like a questionably useful function; it basically wraps normal pattern matching of an `enum` type, and since it can panic it is likely to obfuscate rather than clarify wherever it is used. Indeed, closer inspection reveals you only use this function once, and you can replace this, for example with (I've renamed `BoardValue` to `Cell` following L.F.'s idea):

  ```
  fn get_game_status(&self) -> GameStatus {
      for slice in self.board.get_winnable_slices() {
          if let Cell::Filled(player) = slice[0] {
              if slice[0] == slice[1] && slice[1] == slice[2] {
                  return GameStatus::PlayerWins(*player);
              }
          }
      }
  ```
- Defining `Cell` before `Player` is difficult to follow. Better to put `pub enum Player` at the top and then define `Cell` afterwards.
- The use of `impl Deref` and `impl DerefMut` for `Board` is clever! One thing to consider is that this makes type conversions implicit, so if you do something weird (like calling a function on the underlying `[[Cell; 3]; 3]` that you didn't know existed), the compiler won't give you a type error. I think it is probably worth it for convenience in this case. But an alternative would be to write getters and setters for grid cells, like `fn get_cell(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Cell` and `fn set_cell(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize)`. This could be more extensible later if you add more fields to the `Board` struct.
- Your error type `pub enum PlayError` is great design; extensible for other error types. A problem, though, is that `pub fn play` seems to implicitly panic if given an out-of-range row and column. Since you are already returning Result, I think it would be better to include an out-of-bounds error: i.e.

  ```
  pub fn play(&mut self, row: usize, column: usize) -> Result<GameStatus, PlayError> {
      if row > 2 || column > 2 {
          return Err(PlayError::OutOfBounds)
      }
      if matches!(self.board[row][column], Cell::Filled(_)) {
          return Err(PlayError::AlreadyFilled);
      }
  ```

  This may also simplify and clarify the logic in `main` as you don't can handle the Result type instead of checking the bounds yourself.
- In your `get_all_cells` function, instead of returning a vector you can return an iterator. That works like this:

  ```
  fn iter_cells(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Cell> {
      self.iter().flatten()
  }
  ```

  This eliminates a needless iterator-to-vector-to-iterator conversion, since you are only using `get_all_cells` in order to iterate anyway. So in `get_game_status` you would just use `if self.board.iter_cells().all(...) { ... }`
- The board length `3` is a magic constant. Since it's only used in a few places I would prefer `const BOARD_ROWS: usize = 3` and `const BOARD_COLS: usize = 3`. This is also fun because you can then try out tic-tac-toe on other board dimensions like 2-by-5 or something, but you would have to re-implement `get_winnable_slices` in a more general way.
- Minor but worth thinking about: I am overall not sure that having both `Game` and `Board` types is worth it. It is not clear that there is functionality specific to `Board` that isn't just the fact that it's a grid of cells. If you move `impl fmt::Display`, `get_winnable_slices`, and `iter_cells` to `Game`, then you can get rid of `Board` entirely and avoid the indirection of having to implement `Deref` and `DerefMut`. Or you could still keep these functions separate, but more in a functional style rather than object-oriented.